# Proxy Error while installing express using npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

When I am trying to install express by npm getting below error.

D:\testing node>npm install express -l

```
npm WARN package.json testnode@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json testnode@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json testnode@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "-l"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 103.245.222.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 103.245.222.162:443]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '103.245.222.162',
npm ERR!   port: 443,
npm ERR!   parent: 'testnode' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\testing node\npm-debug.log
```

**Although I have removed proxy too but even after that getting the same**
**Tried running npm as administrative**

Comment: Also there is no environment variable like HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY.

Answer (score 0):

Change your proxy setting using 
set http_proxy=http://hostname:port